# Binary tree on a vector

Tags: tree, binary-tree, computation

I want to know this question (only one is correct)
A implementation of a binary tree with a vector:
a) Only advisable if the tree is a heap
b) only advisable if the tree is decision
c) We can use a vector if we want to build search trees
d) The tree has to be ordened for use the vector
e) None of the previous

I would like to know the answer and why, I have problems with a,c,e, i wouldnt decide my response.

Comment: What exactly *is* the question here?

Comment: I want to know the true answer of the five

Comment: But none of those are actual questions, they're seemingly answers to a question which isn't clear. "A implementation of a binary tree with a vector" <-- not a question.

Comment: A implementation of a binary tree with a vector:
a) Only advisable if the tree is a heap
b) only advisable if the tree is decision
c) We can use a vector if we want to build search trees
d) The tree has to be ordened for use the vector
e) None of the previous

Comment: So you don't want to know the answer to multiple questions, you want to know which of the five options most closely fits the statement "A implementation of a binary tree with a vector is a good idea if ..." ?

Comment: yes, only one is correct